# Troubles with classes and inheritance in Python chess game

Tags: python, class, inheritance, chess

Please help me to understand

I have a tuple like this

Board : tuple[int, list[Piece]]

which contains the size of the board and objects of pieces, their coordinated and if they are True (white side or _side) or False (Black side)

One of the step it is to check if there is a piece on the cell and also check if this piece belongs to the same side as it then cannot move there.

Outside the functions I can create and check the objects like this R1.side_ and I can compare them, but what about inside the Class?

The function is_piece_at can easily tell me if there is a piece at this location, but I cannot work out how to check the side of piece inside the Class.

```
class Piece:
    pos_x : int 
    pos_y : int
    side_ : bool #True for White and False for Black
    def __init__(self, pos_X : int, pos_Y : int, side_ : bool):
        '''sets initial values'''
        self.pos_x=pos_X 
        self.pos_y=pos_Y
        self.side_=side_ #maybe set it to True?
    def __str__(self):#
        return f"{self.pos_x} {self.pos_y} {self.side_}"
```

```
class Rook(Piece):
    def __init__(self, pos_X : int, pos_Y : int, side_ : bool):
        '''sets initial values by calling the constructor of Piece'''
        super().__init__(pos_X, pos_Y, side_)


    def can_reach(self, pos_X : int, pos_Y : int, B: Board) -> bool:
        '''
        checks if this rook can move to coordinates pos_X, pos_Y
        on board B according to rule [vertical and Horizontal move] and 
        [Rule4] A piece of side X (Black or White) cannot move to a location occupied by a piece of side X.] (see section Intro)
        Hint: use is_piece_at
        '''
```

```
def is_piece_at(pos_X : int, pos_Y : int, B: Board) -> bool:
    '''checks if there is piece at coordinates pox_X, pos_Y of board B''' 
    # B sarà del tipo [dimensione, [pezzo1, pezzo2, pezzo3, ...]]
    if (pos_X > B[0] or pos_Y > B[0]) :
      return False # o in alternativa un raise exception
    for piece in B[1] :
      if (piece.pos_x == pos_X and piece.pos_y == pos_Y) :
        return True
    return False
```

```
R0=Rook(1,1,True)
R1=Rook(2,2,False)
R2=Rook(3,3,False)
t.append(R0)
t.append(R1)
t.append(R2)
Board=[5,t]
Board
```

```
R1.side_==R0.side_
R1.pos_x
```

Comment: I wouldn't use a boolean here, even though you can, rather maybe an `enum`, but in either case, `piece.side_ == piece.side_` *should work*

Comment: and inside the class, you would just use `self.side_`.  Note, this annotation is incorrect: `B: Board`